# How to make visible only one listitem at a time in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, visibility, android-adapter

I am using `RecyclerView` and it has two `TextView`s; one for a question and one for an answer. Following is the view for reference. By default, I set the answer `TextView` to invisible to the user. Now if the user clicks on button answer will be visible. So far it works fine, now what I want is if user open answer for question 1 answer will be visible, now if the user clicks second listitem button then first answer `TextView` should be hidden. I want only one answer to be visible at a time.

Question 1 (Button)

### Answer

Question 2 (Button)

### Answer

Question 3 (Button)

### Answer

Question 4 (Button)

### Answer

```
 public class BuyerFaqsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<BuyerMemberShipFAQParent> brandList;

private Context context;
private int counter;


class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvans,tvfaq;
    public ImageView ivImage;

    MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        tvfaq = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_layout_faqtv);
        tvans = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_layout_answertv);
        ivImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_layout_ivarrow);
    }
}

public BuyerFaqsAdapter(final Context context, final ArrayList<BuyerMemberShipFAQParent> brandList) {
    this.brandList = brandList;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.row_layout_faq_expand_parent, parent, false);


    return new BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.tvfaq.setText(brandList.get(position).getFAQParentText());
    holder.tvans.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.tvans.setText(brandList.get(position).getFAQAnswerText());
    holder.itemView.setId(position);
    counter = 1;
    holder.ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (counter == 1) {
                holder.tvans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_faq_up);
                counter = 2;
            }
            else {
                holder.tvans.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_faq);
                counter = 1;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return brandList.size();
}
```

Comment: you want to show one answer at a time ?

Comment: yes i want one answer at a time visible

Comment: can you post the recylerview layout and adapter code ?

Comment: You're checking on counter variable which is always equal to 1. Check on holder.getAdapterPosition() instead. You should keep a reference of the last clicked index in your adapter class and update it each time a row is clicked. Then, check if the holder.getAdapterPosition() in your click callback is different from the last clicked index and update the UI accordingly

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi can you help me with answer please :)

Comment: @Nilima I need the complete code of your adapter

Comment: If you want to open answer click at a time then you need to check it with by taking one int variable with -1 value.

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi please check updated code

Comment: There is only one thing to do by comparing  position as i said above and notify your adapter.

Comment: @Piyush can you please help me with answer

Comment: @Nilima I have already done. But i am not able to share snippet using hastiebin.

Comment: @Piyush can you please use other pasties or paste answer here

Comment: @Nilima Check this https://pastebin.com/VnL5C1wj

Comment: @Nilima check my answer please

Comment: @Piyush on buttons click what to add ?

Comment: @Piyush methods are not in use, it shows can not reslove setselectedmethod and where we used getselected method, https://pastebin.com/WBZ6stdC

Comment: U need to pass ur activity context in adapter constructor so you can access that method.

Comment: Also you did wrong in your code.

Comment: @Piyush i passed context only, but could not find solution. can you please tell what to change

Comment: Check this now https://pastebin.com/S7u507dj @Nilima

Comment: @Piyush need your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52453595/samsung-device-paypal-not-able-to-open-paymentactivity

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested it because I don't have your layout files but you should do something like this:

```jave
public class BuyerFaqsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<BuyerMemberShipFAQParent> brandList;

    private Context context;
    private MyViewHolder lastClickedHolder;


    public BuyerFaqsAdapter(final Context context, final ArrayList<BuyerMemberShipFAQParent> brandList) {
        this.brandList = brandList;
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    public BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_layout_faq_expand_parent, parent, false);


        return new BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tvfaq.setText(brandList.get(position).getFAQParentText());
        holder.tvans.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tvans.setText(brandList.get(position).getFAQAnswerText());
        holder.itemView.setId(position);

        holder.ivImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (lastClickedHolder != null) {
                    collapse(lastClickedHolder);
                }
                expand(holder);
                lastClickedHolder = holder;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return brandList.size();
    }

    private void collapse(BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder) {
        holder.tvans.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_faq_up);
    }

    private void expand(BuyerFaqsAdapter.MyViewHolder holder) {
        holder.tvans.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ivImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_faq);
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvans, tvfaq;
        public ImageView ivImage;

        MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tvfaq = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_layout_faqtv);
            tvans = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_layout_answertv);
            ivImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_layout_ivarrow);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: behaviour is very weried, opens on next items click and close not working

Comment: @Nilma please share your code with a public repository

Comment: please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52712981/how-to-get-nonce-in-braintree-using-express-checkout